# Negrito "<b>" não aplica em um intervalo

Tags: html

Em uma `table`, se eu aplicar o negrito (`<b>`) por fora das células (`<td>`), ele não funciona:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <b>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
    <td>Cell C</td>
    <td>Cell D</td>
    </b>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Se aplicar dentro, (óbvio) funciona, mas tenho que colocar em todos que quiser:

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Cell A</b></td>
        <td>Cell B</td>
        <td><b>Cell C</b></td>
        <td>Cell D</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

---

- **Por que** isso ocorre?
- A única forma seria **colocar manualmente em cada célula, ou por** `CSS`?
- Funciona em **intervalo de outros tipos de tags**?

Comment: mas se você quer tanto usar `<b>` você pode coloca-lo fora da `<table>`, mas CSS é mais recomendável e deixa o HTML mais limpo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com o [living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element) do elemento `Table` apenas os seguintes elementos podem ser utilizados com 'filhos':

- [caption](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-caption-element)
- [colgroup](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-colgroup-element)
- [thead](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-thead-element)
- [tbody](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tbody-element)
- [tr](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tr-element)
- [tfoot](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tfoot-element)
- [script/template](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-2)

Isso acontece porque o elemento tem como objetivo a apresentação de dados tabulares, e não formatação. Para isso, utilize CSS:

```css
td.bold {font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='bold'>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
    <td class='bold'>Cell C</td>
    <td>Cell D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

### *"Por que isso ocorre?"*

Porque um elemento `TD` deve vir em seguida de um elemento `TR`, não há espaço para elementos entre eles.

### *"A única forma seria colocar manualmente em cada célula, ou por CSS?"*

Sim, em cada `TD` (horrível), ou usando CSS, dai pode ser uma classe ou aplicando direto da `TR` também, que funcionaria no seu caso

### *"Funciona em intervalo de outros tipos de tags?*"

Sim, pode estar dentro de uma `DIV` por exemplo, e afetar todos os elementos em seguida, mas a tag `<B>` está descontinuada, é considerada obsoleta ([leia mais aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b)) e por isso recomendado usar o atributo CSS para isso, `font-weight: bold` por exemplo:

```
tr {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

Aqui só um exemplo, melhor aplicar uma classe senão todas as linhas ficarão com negrito, ou se for um título usar `TH`